# Soap Web Service client from java class using saaj

Tags: java, web-services, soap, saaj

I am working in application in wish i need to invoke soap web services. To do so i am using SAAJ. For testing I made the  method  below to call a service. This service return a String  that receives as input.my problem is that the service is called but it doesn't receive the input parameters. Can anyone give me an idea about how to resolve this please?
2. I have also another question, how can i do to invoke a service who has objects as input? 
3. is SAAJ the best solution to create distant client to invoque soap services?
Thank you

```
 public void invokeExtractMetadata(Service service,String path) throws Exception  {
     System.out.println("invoke"); 
    QName serviceName = new QName(service.namespace, service.serviceName);
    QName portName =  new QName(service.namespace, service.portType);

    String  endpointAddress =service.endPointAddress;
    javax.xml.ws.Service myService = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(serviceName);

    myService.addPort(portName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointAddress);



    Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = myService.createDispatch(portName, SOAPMessage.class, javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE);


    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) dispatch; //Use Dispatch as BindingProvider

    MessageFactory factory =  ((SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding()).getMessageFactory();

    SOAPMessage request = factory.createMessage();

    // Request Header
    SOAPHeader header = request.getSOAPHeader();

    // Request Body
    SOAPBody body = request.getSOAPBody();

    // Compose the soap:Body payload
    QName payloadName =   new QName(service.namespace,service.inMsgTag );
    SOAPBodyElement payload = body.addBodyElement(payloadName);

    QName name = new QName("pathT");
    SOAPElement message = payload.addChildElement(name);
    message.addTextNode(path);






    SOAPMessage reply = null; 
    //Invoke Endpoint Operation and read response
    reply = dispatch.invoke(request);
                    //process the reply

    body = reply.getSOAPBody();
    QName responseName =   new QName(service.namespace, service.outMsgTag);
    SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement)body.getChildElements(responseName).next();

    QName elementName = new QName("", "return");

    Iterator t =bodyElement.getChildElements(elementName);
     System.out.println("tt");


     while(t.hasNext()){
         SOAPBodyElement bodyElementTest = (SOAPBodyElement)t.next();
         String valeur = bodyElementTest.getValue();
         System.out.println("valeur"+valeur);

     }

     }
```